# Down lights not functioning properly

Tags: electrical

I have 4 down-lights in a bathroom.

When i turn them on maybe 2 will come on so I switch off again then  back on and 3 may come on then switch off and on then all will come on.

Anyone got any idea whats going on

Comment: What kind of lights?

Comment: Are we talking recessed cans, integral LEDs, ...?

Comment: There LEDs im in uk

Comment: Are you using a single pole switch or could it be a dimmer switch?